# material-ui onDblClick table row

Tags: material-ui

I'm using Material-UI (v1.2.3) w/ Typescript.

I am trying to handle double click for a table row as following:

```
<TableRow onDblClick={that.handleRowDblClick(val)}
```

Unfortunately, it seems this property does not exist on TableRow.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

Does it work with `onDoubleClick`?

An old React issue: [Why is onDoubleClick not named onDblClick?](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6809)